# How to change Ubuntu 19.10's login theme

Tags: gnome, themes

As the title said, I want to know a way to change the login theme. I mean the login interface. Which we long into our system, not the lock screen. Can anyone help me? I've struggled with this for a long time. Thanks very much.

Comment: The default DM is `gdm3`, so maybe useful is https://wiki.debian.org/GDM  Sorry I use `sddm` so have little experience with `gdm3`

Answer (score 1):

The file that may concern is ubuntu.css which is located in usr/share/gnome-shell/theme.So you have to edit the file .First i will suggest you to take a backup of the file
`sudo cp /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css.bak`

Now edit : file the directive named **lockDialogGroup** in the ubuntu.css file .
now change the **background** value to your desired image file location.
You can also set *background-repeat* value with **no-repeat** and many more as you wish. 
an exapmle : 
`#lockDialogGroup {
   background: #ffff url(file:///home/background.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}`

You can also edit gdm3.css file if you want . its located in /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme too .

Happy customizing!

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But in my `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme` flolder, I just found gdm3.css and gnome-shell.css. Which one should I modify? By the way, what's gdm3/css used for?